# Classic ASP + Caching Database Data for Reuse

Tags: asp-classic

We have a Classic ASP web app that has many dynamic dropdown lists for form searches. The data for these lists rarely changes. Maybe once per year. Everytime a user visits the pages, the database is queried to build these lists. I would like a better way to do this. I am sure there is a way to query the DB once, and create the dropdowns once and then reuse these. However, I am not sure how this can be done.

Here is an example dropdown that I would like to cache:

```
<%sql = "SELECT personType_Id, personTypeName FROM PersonTypes ORDER BY personTypeName"
Set DB = ConnectRead ()
Set rs = DB.Execute (sql)%>
<select name="personType_Id">
    <option value="">All</option>
<%  WHILE NOT (rs.EOF) %>
<option value="<%=rs ("personType_Id")%>" <%IF (CINT(searchPersonTypeId) = rs("personType_Id")) THEN Response.Write("Selected") %>><%=rs ("personTypeName")%></option>
<% rs.MoveNext()
   WEND %>
</select>
<% db_CloseRs rs
   db_CloseConn DB  %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would store the html output in the Application object (http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_application.asp). It's perfect to use as a cache as it's memory storage shared over all users (in contrary to a session which is per user and only for the time a session exists).

Implementation example

```
html = GetHtmlForSelect("personType")

Function GetHtmlForSelect(selectName)
   If IsEmpty(Application(selectName)) Then
      'retrieve from database
      Application(selectName) = BuildHtmlWithdatabase(selectName)
   End If
   Return Application(selectName)
End Function
```

The function returns HTML from the Application. If it's not available, if updates the Application object before it returns the result.

ps. I'm not sure if your need to check on IsEmpty, IsNull Or Len() = 0...

Comment: I like this option, but I have a few questions... Do I just add the code to global.asa or use the Application object? How much overhead would storing 5-6 dropdowns add to the server?

Comment: In this example you don't use the global.asa, but that's also an option. 
In my example you can easily update the 'cache' by clearing the Application(selectname) and call the function again. If you store logic in the global.asa, it's more difficult to update the cache. Then clearing works the same, but you need to insert the values again and it's not possible to call a function in the global.asa, so you need to duplicate code then.
I don't think you should worry about the overhead, this is really minimal as long as the select boxes don't contain millions of options ;-)

Comment: I do some similar but I use recordset.GetRows() to store the result from the database as an array and  store this in an Application object. Might save a little space over storing all the HTML. I also record the time that the object was last retrieved in another application object, and I have a function that returns the data after it checks that the data has already been retrieved and is within the cache time I set, otherwise it retrieves fresh data from the database.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So basically create the Application variable the first time its needed then reuse it. If it is null/empty/=0, recreate it. I like that.

One more clarification: In my code sample from the initial question, I pass a variable to the dropdown "searchPersonTypeId" in order to make a certain option in the dropdown list as "Selected". It there a way to do this using your method?

Comment: The 'Selected' can change each time, so I would go for John's option: store the record data and rebuild the HTML each time. Then the selection can be different each time.

Answer (score 2):

Have the database write-out the actual HTML to a file, include that file in your ASP. Set up a trigger on that table  (or query) to re-generate the file. All this can be performed inside [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services).

Comment: Be aware that you need to have file write access on the web server, which might not be the case.

Comment: I tried a similar method before but found that a user might retrieve an error if they tried to access the page while the file was in the middle of being written.

Comment: Write new file. Delete old file. Rename new file to old file.